# How to concatenate three panda DataFrames with no rows mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, concatenation

I'm having some issues concatenating three DataFrames with Pandas. The rows for one of my DataFrame is not in line with the other two (see code and output below):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

List = ['LU0526609390:EUR', 'IE00BHBX0Z19:EUR', 'LU1076093779:EUR', 'LU1116896363:EUR']
df = pd.DataFrame(List, columns=['List'])
urls = 'https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/summary?s='+ df['List']

dfs =[]
results = pd.DataFrame()
for url in urls:
    print(url)
    r = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    elemList = soup.find('title')
    df0 = pd.DataFrame(elemList, columns = ['Fund Name'])
    df0["Fund Name"] = df0["Fund Name"].str.replace("summary - FT.com", "", regex=True)
    table1 = soup.find_all('table')[0]
    table2 = soup.find_all('table')[1]
    df1 = pd.read_html(str(table1), index_col=0)[0].T
    df2 = pd.read_html(str(table2), index_col=0)[0].T
    df = pd.concat([df0, df1, df2], axis=1)
    dfs.append(df)

pd.concat(dfs).to_csv(r'/Users/Test.csv', index=False)
```

My Output is the following:

[image]

It looks like the rows on my df0 DataFrame (column: 'Fund Name') is not in line with the rows of my other DataFrames. Would be very grateful if someone could let me know why this is happening. Thanks!

Comment: Try putting `ignore_index=True` in your call to `pd.concat` and see if it helps

Comment: @Riley I still seem to have the same issue but thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is add `Fund Name` column like first column in [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
dfs =[]
results = pd.DataFrame()
for url in urls:
    print(url)
    r = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    elemList = soup.find('title')
    
    table1 = soup.find_all('table')[0]
    table2 = soup.find_all('table')[1]
    df1 = pd.read_html(str(table1), index_col=0)[0].T
    df2 = pd.read_html(str(table2), index_col=0)[0].T
    # print (df2)
    df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
    df.insert(0, 'Fund Name', elemList)
    df["Fund Name"] = df["Fund Name"].str.replace("summary - FT.com", "", regex=True)
    dfs.append(df)
```